# Rstudio Keras attention_layer application

Tags: r, keras, attention-model

I was hardly trying to find an example of a (quite) recently introduced `layer_attention` for Keras in the Rstudio's library.

I got the net working in two fashions: `LSTM(return_sequences = T) - Attention - LSTM(return_sequences = F)`; `LSTM(return_sequences = T) - Attention - Flatten` before the dense layers. Note in my code that `layer_flatten` is commented; you could comment the second `layer_lstm` instead. Both approaches output 1D tensor, which at least seems to be fitting the expected dimensionality of the NN output.

**What is a correct way, or more sensible?** I am not very experienced in this field...

```
library(keras)

rm(nn_model)

lstm_units <- 16L
lstm_seq_len <- 4L 
nfeatures <- 2L; final_diffs <- 1:3

inputs <- 
  layer_input(shape = list(lstm_seq_len, nfeatures))

lstm_output <- 
  inputs %>% 
  layer_lstm(
    input_shape = list(lstm_seq_len, nfeatures)
    , units = lstm_units
    , activation = 'relu'
    , return_sequences = T
    , stateful = F
    , name = 'lstm1'
  )

predictions <-
  layer_attention(
    inputs = list(lstm_output, lstm_output),
    use_scale = FALSE,
    causal = FALSE,
    batch_size = NULL,
    dtype = NULL,
    name = 'attention',
    trainable = T,
    weights = NULL
  ) %>%
  layer_lstm(
    input_shape = list(lstm_seq_len, nfeatures)
    , units = lstm_units
    , activation = 'relu'
    , return_sequences = F
    , stateful = F
    , name = 'lstm2'
  ) %>%
  #layer_flatten %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64L, activation = NULL, name = 'dense1') %>% 
  layer_batch_normalization(name = 'bn1') %>%  
  layer_activation(activation = "relu", name = 'act1') %>%  
  layer_dense(units = 32L, activation = NULL, name = 'dense2') %>% 
  layer_batch_normalization(name = 'bn2') %>%  
  layer_activation(activation = "relu", name = 'act2') %>%  
  layer_dense(units = length(final_diffs), activation = 'softmax', name = 'dense3')

optimizer <- 
  optimizer_adam(lr = 1e-5)

nn_model <- 
  keras_model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predictions)

nn_model %>% 
  keras::compile(
    optimizer = optimizer,
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics = 'categorical_accuracy'
  )

summary(nn_model)

predict(nn_model, array(runif(lstm_seq_len * nfeatures, 0, 1), dim = c(1, lstm_seq_len, nfeatures)))
```